NLTK package is not working in production but working in development
I have created a web-app using Django. I this web-app I want to add functionality to extract phrases from content. My code is working fine in development but not working in production. Using nltk package I have created a function which gives returns a list of phrases from content. below is my code:
import nltk
from typing import List


def extract_phrases(content: str) -> List:
    # Tokenize text into sentences
    sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(content)
    # Initialize list to store phrases
    phrases = set()

    # Iterate through each sentence
    for sentence in sentences:
        # Tokenize sentence into words
        words = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)

        # Get part-of-speech tags for words
        pos_tags = nltk.pos_tag(words)

        # Initialize list to store phrases in current sentence
        current_phrase = []

        # Iterate through each word and its part-of-speech tag
        for word, pos_tag in pos_tags:
            # If the word is a noun or an adjective, add it to the current phrase
            if pos_tag.startswith("NN") or pos_tag.startswith("JJ"):
                current_phrase.append(word)
            # If the word is not a noun or adjective and the current phrase is not empty,
            # add the current phrase to the list of phrases and reset it
            elif current_phrase:
                phrases.add(" ".join(current_phrase))
                current_phrase = []

        # Add the last phrase from the current sentence (if any)
        if current_phrase:
            phrases.add(" ".join(current_phrase))

    return list(phrases)

The function and entire web-app properly working in development environment. But in production where the nltk module is used that line is not executing.
Note
I have activated my virtual environment and run following code also:
import nltk
nltk.download('all')


We have to provide path of downloaded nltk files.
import nltk

NLTK_PATH = 'path of files'
nltk.data.path.append(NLTK_PATH)

